# How the get the classOf for a scala object type

Tags: scala

I wonder how to get a class object for an object type in Scala. Ok, that is a mouth full because of the double meaning for object. So here an example which will fail:

```
object Main
{
   private [this] val TAG = classOf [Main].getName;
} // Main
```

If `Main` was class it works perfectly. Any ideas?

Answer (score 99, accepted):

```
scala> Main.getClass
res1: java.lang.Class[_] = class Main$
```

Comment: Yes. I see, now it becomes all clear. `object`s have exactly one instance and therefore you call `getClass`. Thanks.

Comment: @Martin Actually, I'd say that's incorrect. `object`s don't _have_ instances at all, because they aren't types; they _are_ the only instances of (compiler-generated) classes, and that's why you can call `getClass`.

Comment: Is their a Way to do this as a compile time Constant so that it can be used for a Java Annotation Attribute of type Class ?

Comment: @MarkusKnecht I don't know one; you may want to ask this as a separate question.

Answer (score 19):

The reason why `classOf[Main]` doesn't work is because `Main` is not a **type**.

Classes and traits define types, objects do not.

Answer (score 10):

Since Main is an object, for your example to work, simply replace your assignment line with;

```
private [this] val TAG = this.getClass.getName;
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to refer an object type. e.g:

```
classOf[Main.type]
```