# Get class of Scala object for annotation

Tags: java, scala, reflection, annotations

I have a use case where I need to do some Java reflection on some Scala objects (don't even ask). Anyway, I sometimes need to add these objects to an annotation, in Scala.

Here's my (java) annotation:

```
@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface MyAnnotation {
   Class<?>[] value();
}
```

And let's say this is my Scala object:

```
object Foo{}
```

In Java, I can reference Foo using my above annotation like this:

```
@MyAnnotation(Foo.class)
class SomeClass{}
```

In Scala, however, I don't see how I can get a type literal from an Object:

```
@MyAnnotation(Array(classOf[Foo]))
class SomeClass{}
```

This fails, with error message:

> not found: type Foo

Is there any way I can reference my Foo object type in a Java annotation? Note that I can't [use `Foo.getClass`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9635563/how-the-get-the-classof-for-a-scala-object-type), because that's a method call, not a constant.

Comment: Try `@MyAnnotation(Array(Foo.getClass)) class SomeClass`. Does it work?

Comment: @DmytroMitin `annotation argument needs to be a constant; found: Foo.getClass()`

Comment: Hmm... reopening. (For the record, link was https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9635563/how-the-get-the-classof-for-a-scala-object-type)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```scala
@MyAnnotation(Array(classOf[Foo.type]))
class SomeClass
```

`classOf[Foo.type]` is allowed since Scala 2.13.4

https://github.com/scala/scala/pull/9279

https://github.com/scala/bug/issues/2453

---

In older Scala you can create a class literal manually using a **whitebox** macro

```scala
def moduleClassOf[T <: Singleton]: Class[T] = macro impl[T]

def impl[T: c.WeakTypeTag](c: whitebox.Context): c.Tree = {
  import c.universe._
  Literal(Constant(weakTypeOf[T]))
}
```

Usage:

```scala
@MyAnnotation(Array(moduleClassOf[Foo.type]))
class SomeClass
```

https://gist.github.com/DmytroMitin/e87ac170d107093a9b9faf2fd4046bd5

Comment: This gives a new error:
`class type required but com.myapp.Foo.type found`

Comment: @SeanPatrickFloyd what is your version of Scala?

Comment: ah crap, my scala is too old (2.12.14)

Comment: @SeanPatrickFloyd can you upgrade to Scala ≥2.13.4?

Comment: @SeanPatrickFloyd Maybe in older Scala a macro can work: `def impl[T: c.WeakTypeTag](c: Context): c.Expr[Class[_]] = {import c.universe._; c.Expr[Class[_]](Literal(Constant(weakTypeOf[T])))}` `def moduleClassOf[T <: Singleton]: Class[_] = macro impl[T]` `moduleClassOf[Foo.type]`

Comment: Eventually, but not in the time frame I need for this.

Comment: @SeanPatrickFloyd can you try the macro? `@MyAnnotation(Array(moduleClassOf[Foo.type])) class SomeClass`

Comment: will do. have never tried macros before, so I have to read up on them first

Comment: the macro object model seems to have changed a lot, can't get this to work. I'm not very experienced at Scala, so that makes it harder.

Comment: @SeanPatrickFloyd I checked. The macro seems not to help in 2.12.14. Again `annotation argument needs to be a constant` :( Currently I can't see an option different from upgrading.

Comment: @SeanPatrickFloyd Just in case, here is the macro https://gist.github.com/DmytroMitin/e87ac170d107093a9b9faf2fd4046bd5

Comment: @SeanPatrickFloyd I finally managed to make this work in 2.12.4. It's enough to make the macro whitebox. Updating my answer.

Comment: @SeanPatrickFloyd If you have questions about macros feel free to ask. Tutorial is here https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/macros/overview.html Sbt settings are here https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Macro-Projects.html

Comment: I doubt I will actually use this until we upgrade to 2.13.x, because Macros are frowned upon in my company, but this is definitely the correct answer, thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66213126/why-does-classofa-type-not-compile